# StringRequest onResponse no funciona

Tags: php, java, android, mysql

Soy nuevo en Android Studio y en el desarrollo de aplicaciones. Actualmente estoy tratando de pasar una app de encuestas que hice en Android Studio + SQL Server a MySql con web service. El problema que tengo es que la app no me pasa de la siguiente línea de código:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OPERACION EXITOSA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Llega a mostrar el Toast pero luego nada, consulto la base de datos y nada tampoco. El código completo es el siguiente:

```
public class comentarios extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener {

Button b_anterior, b_enviar;
EditText observaciones;
String opcion = "", obs = "", sucursal="1";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comentarios);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    recibirDatos();
    /** Relacion de objetos **/
    b_anterior = findViewById(R.id.b_anterior);
    b_enviar = findViewById(R.id.b_enviar);
    observaciones = findViewById(R.id.observaciones);

    /** A la espera de confirmacion **/
    b_anterior.setOnClickListener(this);
    b_enviar.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void recibirDatos(){
    Bundle mainActivity = getIntent().getExtras();
    opcion = mainActivity.getString("Opcion");
}
/** Toma acciones en base al boton seleccionado **/
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b_enviar:
            obs = observaciones.getText().toString();
            ejecutarSericio("https://mipagina.com/insertar.php");
            break;
        case R.id.b_anterior:
            pantallaprincipal();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
public void pantallaprincipal(){
    try{
        Intent activity_main  = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(activity_main);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
private void ejecutarSericio(String URL) {
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OPERACION EXITOSA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("calificacion",opcion);
            parametros.put("sucursal", sucursal);
            parametros.put("obs", obs);
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

El php lo descarto porque pruebo pasar los parámetros por url y funciona correctamente. Alguien que me pueda dar una mano y explicarme que pasa y por qué? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que esperas que pase? onResponse se ejecuta despues de invocar el servicio. Ya sabes que se ha ejecutado, desde onResponse debes llamar a algo otro, lo que se necesita.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y perdón por la demora. Luego de haber echo un buen debug si puedo notar que pasa del onResponse pero por algún motivo me devuelte "OPERACIÓN EXITOSA" pero no me graba los parametros en MySql. Ya probé el php con Postman y funciona de maravilla, alguna idea?